# Space between items, enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I can't make a distance between items
[image]

Comment: I would recommend to use `\frac` instead of `\dfrac`, but without a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem it is difficult to help.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

there is quite complicated to see your code, but one way to do it is by using the package **enumitem**, then your code should be like this:

```
%Preamble
\usepackage{enumitem}
...
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1cm,parsep=0.5cm]
   \item $\frac{1}{2}$
   \item $\frac{1}{2}$
\end{enumerate}
```

it lets you set the spacing between items (itemsep) and between the paragraphs within items (parsep). Then, your result will be

[image]

Comment: The OP's question uses `enumerate*` and a `\dfrac`, so not sure this actually solves the issue.  Even with default settings, with `enumitem` things work fine for me.  FYI, it is always best to post a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages. You can usually use the `article` class (unless the issue is with some septic class).